# How can i set permission on url

Tags: python, django

I am new on Django, 
I have implemented a valid form and now I want to set permission on URL.

When a form is submitted, then it redirects me to this URL

> http://127.0.0.1:8000/success/

Without submitting a form I can manually type the name of the URL `http://127.0.0.1:8000/success/` and it will take me to the same page.

How can I set permission on "success" url, so that user can not manually view the page unless the form is valid and submitted?

Do I need a decorator for this?

Model:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True,null=True) 
    profile_pic = models.ImageField(upload_to='ProfilePicture/', default="ProfilePicture/avatar.png", blank=True)   
    phone = models.IntegerField(default='0', blank=True)
    email = models.EmailField(blank=True)
    date_of_birth = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    address = models.TextField(blank=True)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)  

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Profile'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Profiles'
        ordering = ['-date']

    '''Method to filter database results'''
    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

class CotCode(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    cot_code = models.IntegerField(default='0', blank=True)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True) 

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'CotCode'
        verbose_name_plural = 'CotCode'
        ordering = ['-date']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

Url:

```
path('cot/', TransferCOTView, name='transfer_cot'),
path('success/', SuccessfulView, name='successful_trans'),
```

Views:

```
@login_required
def TransferCOTView(request):
    form = CotCodeForm(request.POST)
    if request.method == "POST":
        if form.is_valid():
            cot_code = form.cleaned_data.get('cot_code')
        try:
            match = CotCode.objects.get(cot_code=cot_code)
            return redirect('site:successful_trans')
        except CotCode.DoesNotExist:
             messages.info(request, "Wrong code")

    else:
        form = CotCodeForm()

    context = {
        'form':form,
    }
    return render(request, 'transfer_cotcode.html', context)

@login_required
def SuccessfulView(request):
    return render(request, 'successful_transfer.html')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple option would be to set a session variable informing that the form was posted and valid and check it before displaying the success page. See session examples here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/sessions/#examples

e.g.

```
def formview(request):
    # process form
    request.session["form_filled"] = True
    # redirect to success

def success(request):
    if not request.session.get("form-filled"):
        raise Http404("Form not filled")
    del request.session["form_filled"] # success view visible once after form is filled
    # return view template
```

You can also check if the user has COT code filled in the success view.

```
def SuccessfulView(request):
    cot_code_exists = CotCode.objects.filter(user=request.user).count()
    if not cot_code_exists:
        raise Http404("Cot code does not exist for user")
    return render(request, 'successful_transfer.html')
```

Comment: Where you got form_filled?

Comment: Set the session variable in TransferCOTView before `return redirect('site:successful_trans')` and then place the check in SuccessfulView before `return render(request, 'successful_transfer.html')`

Note that the user will be able to access the success page for as long the session variable is set. You can delete it and then it the user must refill the form again. 

If you want to check if the user has actual COT code stored that is possible as well.

Comment: This is closer to what i want. But when the form is submitted once, then the user can be able to view successful page. I do not want it to be so, i only want the user to be able to view successful page only when form is submitted.

Comment: Adjusted the answer. You can just delete the session variable and then the form must be filled again for the success page to render.

Comment: I am not too familiar with sessions in django. Do i need to always delete sessions manually? Please make your code clearer.

Comment: Please read the excellent Django session documentation I linked above :) 
Generally you need to delete session variables if you want them gone before session expires.

Comment: It works. Can i redirect this raise Http404("Form not filled") to another view? It shows Page not found when i try to manually view the successful page on yellow background.

Comment: I got was able to redirect to another views with return redirect('site:error_success'). Thanks.